# Inductance - a better analogy than the fact that it is similar to inertia

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance, inertia

This question is to get a feel and  good definition for what inductance actually is.

I have read about the analogy where inductance can be compared to inertia-that the flux through an inductor resists change.

But, while this analogy is fine for understanding induction as a standalone concept, I find it difficult to actually use this reasoning in problem solving. What I mean when I say that it is fine for understanding as a standalone concept is that, if someone asks me, "What is induction?" then I can answer, "It can be said to be like inertia-except that it resists change in flux."

Now , one problem where I can show how this analogy is not helpful is :

If I have been given two loops with some current going through them in the same direction, then what is the net magnetic energy of the system?

My approach:
The net magnetic energy will have the energy due to the self induction of each loop. So, I have : $\frac{1}{2}(L_1i_1^2+L_2i_2^2)$. Now, mutual induction. How does this thing work? If using the inertia analogy, then it must resist change in flux. How exactly does it resist this change?

This is but one of the many places where I get stuck. To simplify, the main doubts are :

1. How does mutual induction affect energy?
2. Is there a better way to get the 'feel' of induction rather than the inertia example?
3. Mutual induction-I understand its formula but what exactly is it? This may seem a bit vague but, like we can get an idea for charge, mass, velocity by understanding the definition once, what is a good definition for inductance in general. Not the formula where it is the flux divided by the current but a good, solid definition like velocity is how fast an object covers a certain distance. The definition should be such that it can be applied for problem solving. As in, if I am stuck, then I should be able to start from the definition of inductance and work my way from there. Unlike now, where I am stuck wondering what part of induction is like inertia.

Comment: What about the definition of inductance can not be applied to "problem solving"? If you want to get "a feel" for what inductance does, then you need to work with electrical circuits that contain inductances on the lab bench. Analogies will only get you so far and if you make one step further, then they will misguide you. One should avoid them and learn to use the actual definitions.

Comment: See.. I am fine with one that does not rely on an analogy. A feel for the subject is appreciated but not necessary. What I would really like is one definition that completely defines induction as some 'solid' concept - the kind where it sticks in your head and you know when you are asked that, "Ah, this is the PERFECT definition. Nothing more, nothing less." You get me? Like the definition of, let's say, flux. The number of field lines passing through a surface. There are no symbols in this definition, but instinctively I can understand that it has something to do with flow through a surface.

Comment: And pure feel doesn't work either. I still struggle with the definition of a field. Sure, I got that feel for it. It just comes from the word. But definition? I got no clue. Maybe if you ask me what's an electric field - force /charge, that's my answer. That is just a relation between quantities, not the stuff I am looking for here in this question.

Comment: I agree that the literal definition of inductance is complex to apply to problems like high frequency circuit design. My preferred electrical engineer simplification is to think of inductance as the additional energy that must be supplied to magnetically "charge" a region of space such that it can sustain a certain current. Mutual inductance represents initial conditions, the "charging" of space by other currents that can increase or decrease the amount of energy that must be supplied by a new current to reach steady state.

Comment: In addition to multiple questions, this is all fairly subjective. e.g. for point 3, why is $v=x/t$ "solid" but $L=\Phi/I$ not? And in assuming you have the same issues with capacitance?

Comment: @user1850479 Inductance is a quantity that is only useful in quasi-static approximation, i.e. when we can neglect the magnetic field that is being created by the changing electric field (see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571161/). In RF applications this is not the case and we have to solve the full equations. The better quantities in those cases are "impedances". However, maybe you can write an answer that explains inductance as a consequence of magnetic field energy density? That might be helpful.

Comment: I did not add v=x/t on purpose as this is just a relation between quantities and not a 'solid' definition where speed is how fast an object covers a certain distance. I used the word 'solid' because, at that time, I couldn't think of a better word to convey what I was looking for. What I actually wanted to convey was that I wanted a definition that would hold up anywhere for whatever applications - hence the word 'solid'. Also, the fact about multiple questions, I think most of them are related so I figured instead of asking each question separately, it would be better asking them together.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Capacitance is fine. I can use the (definition?) relation that C=q/V and work from there. Granted, it isn't a definition, but it still works for most purposes. It still doesn't fit in the category of a definition though. Now, the  subjective part - is it an issue with the way I framed the question?  Because other than the 'solid' part you pointed out, I don't think there are any problems being objective. I have clearly mentioned the cause of the problem as well the answer I am looking for. Maybe you could edit it to look a bit more objective?

Comment: @MockingYak978 How is $C=q/V$ not a definition but $v=x/t$ a definition? You need words? So... Capacitance tells you how much charge separation you need been the plates per voltage difference between the plates?

Comment: I did not say it is a defintion. See my comment. I have clearly said that it is a relation and NOT a definition. I did not include v=x/t in my original question precisely to avoid this confusion. C=q/v is NOT a DEFINITION, it is a RELATION but it works for most purposes. I have stressed this point a lot. Are there any other points to improve on though?

Comment: Still a relation man. Call it what you will, a definition or a relation, in the end, you know and I do what is what. Maybe you are trying to say that some quantities have to be 'explained' (is that a better word?) purely as a relationship with something else? I agree. You can do that. But what I have asked in the question is something 'better' for induction. I do not mind if you have a 'better' way of explaining the inertia example already discussed.It would be great if you contribute something in the vein of the question though.Or we could keep arguing about the semantics all day. Your call.

Comment: A really nice example of this would be what @user1850479 commented. It worked (for me) and it worked much better than the inertia example. It was a really sweet way to imagine induction.

Comment: "*...solid definition like velocity is how fast an object covers a certain distance.*" So you meant relation here? Or codifying this into an equation moves it from a definition to a relation? Many definitions are represented by equations; I think this supposed distinction might be what is holding you back.

Comment: You might have a point here. Let's forget about the relation and definition stuff. Can you give a better 'explanation' for induction? How you imagine the concept will be appreciated too. How you imagine means how you get a feel for the topic.

Answer (score 3):

> This question is to get a feel and good definition for what inductance actually is.
>
> I have read about the analogy where inductance can be compared to inertia-that the flux through an inductor resists change.

The thing about analogies is that a good analogy has three key aspects:

1. the mapping between the analogy and the original is clear and easy to remember
2. the analogy quantitatively reproduces the most important behavior of the original
3. the analogy is simpler than the original

The problem with almost all circuit theory analogies is that they fail on 3), inevitably the original circuit theory principle is simpler than the mechanical analogy. In addition, the inertia analogy fails on 1), but maybe it is just me that has a hard time remembering how the analogy goes.

So usually you are better off just learning the circuit theory concept directly, without analogy. In circuit theory the primary quantities of interest are voltage and current. So the clearest definition of inductance is: $$ V = L \frac{d I}{dt}$$ I have yet to see any analogy that is simpler than that. And since $V$ and $I$ are easy to measure, it is not difficult to build up practical intuition directly.

Once we have the inductance formula we can simply integrate power to get energy: $$E= \int P \ dt = \int V I \ dt = \frac{1}{2} L I^2$$ So directly from standard circuit theory we know that an inductor stores some sort of energy. The energy can be put into the inductor at one time and then pulled out later.

A little bit of physics lets us know that this energy is stored in the magnetic field produced by the current. Now, with that small extra clue from outside of circuit theory, mutual inductance is not too difficult to understand. Magnetic fields can overlap. When the magnetic fields of two inductors overlap then it is possible for energy to be put into one inductor, go through the overlapping field to the other and be pulled out there.

For two mutual inductors the energy is $$ E= \frac{1}{2} L_1 I_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} L_2 I_2^2 + M \ I_1 I_2 $$ The mutual inductance parameter is $M=\sqrt{k L_1 L_2}$ where $0<k<1$ is a parameter that describes how much the magnetic fields overlap.

The inertia example is not very good for self inductance and I cannot see how it can possibly be used for mutual inductance. Just learn these concepts directly, without analogies. To get an intuitive feel you can solve lots of homework problems or build lots of actual circuits. My preference is for building circuits as the best way to gain intuition.